# Cortex-A7 MOESI state encoding

Tags: caching, arm

In Cortex-A7 TRM, we can access internal L1 cache related memory via CP15 instructions. We can retreive Tag RAM/Dirty RAM MOESI state of specific cache line. As stated [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0464f/BABDIJAD.html).

However, it is not mentioned anywhere the detail about the 4-bit MOESI encoding (e.g. 000 refer to what state, etc.). Not anywhere in Armv7-A TRM either. Also, it said 4-bit, but won't 3-bit suffice to encode the 5 MOESI states (UC,UD,SC,SD,I).

Did I miss something?

Comment: You're assuming the states would be encoded numerically - I don't know, but my gut feeling is that that seems pretty unlikely (due to how it would complicate the hardware). At a pure guess, it would seem somewhat more plausible to be a bitmask of MESI, with `O == M | S`.

Comment: Ah, no, assuming it's similar to [Cortex-A53](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0500g/BABDIJAD.html#CHDBCGDH), it looks rather more complicated than that. There are almost certainly other fiddly internal details encoded in those 'x' bits too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like ARM only provide these information to its Debug and Silicon partners. I posted on ARM Community with an answer : https://community.arm.com/thread/10498